# Android heap growing when restarting application

Tags: android, memory-management, heap-memory, andengine

Hi iv'e read around on errors having to do with grow heap in android

```
08-13 21:46:22.382: I/dalvikvm-heap(10859): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.578MB for 2400016-byte allocation
```

Below is the log(filtered) where i repeatedly just back out of my application and start it again over and over again. As you can se the heap grows for for each restart. How can that be? Shouldn't the apps heap get cleared when completely exited?

If i make any change in the code and restart the application the heap resets to its original value. Is this behaviour normal?

The same heap growth also happens everytime i switch activities within my application. I programmed my app in andengine. I got the heap up to 80MB and loading got much slower with the bigger heapsize.

```
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.198MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.354MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.350MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.350MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.406MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.268MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.265MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.264MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.818MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.814MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.813MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.813MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.421MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.427MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.426MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13094): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.426MB for 2400016-byte allocation
//**-Not A log message: here i simply changed a variables name and restarted**
I/dalvikvm-heap(13497): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.995MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13497): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.002MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13497): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.002MB for 2400016-byte allocation
I/dalvikvm-heap(13497): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.002MB for 2400016-byte allocation
```

It's like a memory leak that is retained after closing the app, in the app i do use sharedPreferences to save things. But i fail to see how that can have an effect here. Any ideas?

Comment: Images? Calling Recycle?

Comment: @mike, yeah i tried that, did some heap dumps. But i don't understand it really,what do you mean calling recycle?

Answer (score 1):

Android applications don't simply close, see this nice blogpost on the topic:
http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2010/05/when-to-include-exit-button-in-android.html

The heap grows because your application does not close, it is just hidden. Still, it seems you do in fact have a memory leak. The heap shrinks when you change a variable name because a new apk is generated, your application on the phone gets killed and the application is reinstalled.

Comment: Nice read, though under the "Kill Everything When Not in Use" headline he doesn't really explain how or even if you can do that programmaticly?

Is there a way to close an activity? is what i am wondering then, since activity.finish(); is fake

Comment: I did check onStop() and onDestroy() (my app calls both of them) and according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

onDestroy() seems to mean that the activity should be dead after it, and yet my heap grows...

Comment: ...Sigh... I want to be a good programmer, but i just found the most horribly ugly piece of code which, if inserted where i exit my activities, solve my problem.

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

So very against all good practises for android, and yet i don't know if i can resist using it...

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk , good video! Think i found the origin of my leak, even though the whole concept of an activity not totally closing perplexing